# Coffee too less for Frenchpress

Tags: brewing-process, flavor, health, french-press

I am new to frenchpress coffee and love the rich flavour of coffee it makes. However I am not sure if I am doing it right. The coffee beans I had grinder packet says 7g of coffee in 180ml of water.

When done properly, it makes less than a quarter of a standard mug. 
Is it ok for me too add more grams of coffee with additional water to equal amounts?

How would I know if this is too much strong and can be dangerous because the more grams I put in the more stronger it get. Plus 7g and 180 ml of water won’t let me push down the bat of frenchpress as it’s so low water so it is already on bottom.

Comment: For 2 mugs full try 3 large spoons of coffee  (about 22-25g?) and 700ml water at your preferred brewing temp (I tend to brew at somewhat cooler temperatures). 2min, stirr, 2min, press. Or, do what I do and leave it for 10 minutes without stirring.

Comment: @greenglass by large spoon, do you mean table or teaspoon.

Comment: Dessert spoon, heaped (about 15ml when not heaped?). I'm not too precise about it.

Answer (score 4):

The instructions have poor wording, instead use 7g PER 180ml of water, and make as many cups as you like / your french press can hold.

Personally I use an 8 cup french press, I use roughly 50g of coffee, and fill with water high enough to be full when in full bloom (about 30 seconds after you add water and the coffee is expanding, and letting off c02) After about 45 seconds, I give it a quick stir, and top the french press up with about another ounce or so of water and cover for 4 minutes.

The ratio of coffee per water is a suggestion ONLY.  Typically I recommend 8-9g per 120g of water (If I recall, SCAA standard is 9g per 120g water?)  Use it as a starting place, and adjust based on your taste, and how much coffee you want to brew.

Just a note, I go lighter than my suggested ratios in a french press because it brews stronger.  The 8-9g works well with a drip brewer.

Oh.. one other thing!  You are going to have a hard time making *dangerous* coffee, unless you consider tasting bad dangerous, so don't worry about it being a risk if you are adding too much coffee.  If you stick to the rough suggestions in this post, and other comments on this thread, you are going to get in the ballpark of where you are wanting to go, and then you just fine tune to your personal preference.  And if you manage to make truly dangerous coffee.. make sure to repost the recipe.. I think I could use some of that right about now!!

Comment: +1 for "And if you manage to make truly dangerous coffee.. make sure to repost the recipe.. I think I could use some of that right about now!!"

Comment: I think you wanted to say 120ml of water instead of 120 grams, I am finding a way to keep me up whenever I have it.

Comment: starbucks Coffee Engineer recommends 2 tbs PER 6oz.

Comment: Today I had done an experiment, 6 teaspoons with 4 cups of water. It makes around 2 tbs PER 6oz.I guess.

Comment: 120g of water is 120ml fyi.

Comment: @NateM. Is grams not as equal to ml? Roughly how much one mug is in ml?

Comment: @Nofel In terms of pure water, 1g=1ml.  One average mug I would guess is 6-8 ounces which would be 168g-224g.

Comment: @NateM.So I had a teaspoon, and I want 50g of coffee in 8, By a calculation of grams into a teaspoon, It makes 14 teaspoons. Is that right? I got this French press, Which makes 3 mugs of coffee. I wonder how you make 8 cups out of it?

Comment: @Nofel coffee 'cups' is a traditional measurement that varies by manufacturer but is typically in the neighborhood of 5 oz.  As for the teaspoon measurement, it's difficult to translate teaspoons to grams.  I could say any number of scoops, teaspoons or tablespoons but without actually knowing the shape of the spoon etc, it could end up any amount.  Starbucks recommendation on scoops usually ends up a bit strong for me if I recall, but that would be a good starting place.  So.. 2 tbs / 6 oz, then say about 15 tbs for an 8 cup pot and then adjust according to taste.